# BigQuery Stream Lost the stream data but there are no error reported

Tags: google-bigquery, streaming

```
$insertResponse = $bqTable->insertRows($insertRows);

      if ($insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
            return true;
      } else {
            foreach ($insertResponse->failedRows() as $row) {
                foreach ($row['errors'] as $error) {
                    Log::error('Streaming to BigQuery Error: ' . $error['reason'] . ' ' . $error['message']);
                }
            }
            return false;
      }
```

I used the above code (copied from the php client sample codes).

Basically, what it does is. If the streaming successful, I will return true, and if the streaming failed, I will return false.

I have 524845 rows to insert. To avoid the over size error, for each 1000 rows, I called the above stream statement. And then for the last 845 rows, I called the stream statement again.

if the streaming is successful (return true), I will continue to stream next 1000 rows. If the streaming fails, then I will stop the full streaming process.

I found that bigquery streaming is not stable. In my tests, most times, I had all the 534845 rows streamed into the table. But once a while, I lost some rows. Such as one time I only had 522845 rows streamed. No error reported/logged.

Due to I stream 1000 rows each time, it seems two of my stream activities failed, I lost 2000 rows. But there is no error report, also if it reports error, my code will stop.

Please advise what should I do next to debug this BigQuery Streaming issue.

Comment: Due to there are no streaming errors logged. I added codes to log the successful streaming activities. Next time, if I see the lost data cases, I should be able to dig out the successful streaming logs to see if there are more info I can find to help me debug or to send to Google Cloud support team.

Answer (score 1):

Is an insertId being provided while inserting rows? If so, is it possible the insertIds may be duplicated? It could cause BigQuery to discard what it believes to potentially be duplicate rows.